# Is <img> tag allowed inside <li> in Semantic HTML?

Tags: html, image, html-lists

whicth tag are allowed inside the `li` tag?

`div`?
`img`?
`span`?
`a` (href)?

I think `div` is not allowed. But `img`, `span` and `a` are allowed. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Every tag is allowed. I tested in Firefox: img, span, a, even the div.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can put pretty much any of them inside a li. But different person has different opinion. Some will disagree with putting a div inside a list item, but according to the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri+with_options) you actually can do that. But still, if you need to check or need to use nested elements, you can use W3C validator or any other tools available online.

```html
<ul>
   <li>
      <span>Some text</span>
   </li>
    <li>
      <p><a href="#">link</a></p>
   </li>
    <li>
      <img  width="150" height="150" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633114127451-558041183c3b?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" alt="alt" />
   </li>
   <li>
      <div>
       <input type = "text" />
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```